# How to display "soft" word, from string "Anmsoft" in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

How to display "soft" word, from string "Anmsoft" in oracle 11g or 10g?

Comment: please specify the problem in a more general way, because you can `select 'soft' from dual` to display "soft" word..

Comment: Say i hv a emp's lname as Anmsoft, now i want to display the wrd 'soft' from dat particular string, without using dual. Maybe a function say...SUBSTR. Even tried this bt no luck so far...

Answer (score 0):

this is an answer to the question even if i'm not sure what the problem is exactly:

```
select case 
         when lname = 'Anmsoft' then 'soft'
         else lname
       end lname
from emp;
```

Comment: works just fine on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/766b2/1/0 - you might want to loose the `;` if you are working in a single-query environment..?

Comment: Yup wrked dis time... Bt displayed entire content of lname... Is der any way to print only "soft" ? Does SUBSTR wrks ?